How to safely expose a Lambda to consumers in another accounts and regions
I have a lambda in Account A region us-west-2. Lambda already lives in a VPC with strict SG and private subnets.
I want to make it possible so another accounts B, C, D can hit it via API Gateway (or any other option). Calls to API GW may (or may not, for simplicity) occur from distinct regions.
Hosts should be able to use a Private Zone resolved URL to call hosts. In defect it would be great if they could just call API GW directly and safely.
Going for VPC and endpoints solution, I'd love to make it so these calls happen through Private Links for security and velocity.
When it comes to peering, all my subnets are 10.0.0.0/16 in both accounts. We don't need account B, C, etc calling hosts in account A (where API GW on top of lambda lives), the only need is accounts B, C, etc hosts being able to call a single API GW URL in account A.
This is my assumption and design in mind.
+-------------------+        +-------------------+        +-------------------+
|    Account B      |        |    Account C      |        |    Account D      |
| (Region varies)   |        | (Region varies)   |        | (Region varies)   |
|                   |        |                   |        |                   |
| +---------------+ |        | +---------------+ |        | +---------------+ |
| |   EC2/ECS/    | |        | |   EC2/ECS/    | |        | |   EC2/ECS/    | |
| |   Fargate     | |        | |   Fargate     | |        | |   Fargate     | |
| |  10.0.0.0/16  | |        | |  10.0.0.0/16  | |        | |  10.0.0.0/16  | |
| +-------+-------+ |        | +-------+-------+ |        | +-------+-------+ |
|         |         |        |         |         |        |         |         |
|   +-----v-----+   |        |   +-----v-----+   |        |   +-----v-----+   |
|   | PrivateLink|   |        |   | PrivateLink|   |        |   | PrivateLink|   |
|   | Endpoint   |   |        |   | Endpoint   |   |        |   | Endpoint   |   |
|   +-----------+   |        |   +-----------+   |        |   +-----------+   |
+--------|-----------+        +--------|-----------+        +--------|-----------+
         |                             |                             |
         |                             |                             |
         |         AWS PrivateLink     |                             |
         +-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
                                       |
                                       |
                          +------------v-------------+
                          |      Account A           |
                          |    (Region: us-west-2)   |
                          |                          |
                          | +----------------------+ |
                          | |   VPC (10.0.0.0/16)  | |
                          | |                      | |
                          | | +------------------+ | |
                          | | |  Private Subnet  | | |
                          | | |                  | | |
                          | | |  +-----------+   | | |
                          | | |  | API       |   | | |
                          | | |  | Gateway   |   | | |
                          | | |  +-----+-----+   | | |
                          | | |        |         | | |
                          | | |    +---v---+     | | |
                          | | |    |Lambda |     | | |
                          | | |    +-------+     | | |
                          | | |                  | | |
                          | | +------------------+ | |
                          | |                      | |
                          | +----------------------+ |
                          |                          |
                          +--------------------------+

Some upfront questions:

This sounds like VPC Endpoint Service, but it also seems like the option is a Network Load Balancer, not an ALB. NLB won't accept Lambda as target. Then, what's the right approach here?
Despite hosts in different regions, could I just enable API GW IAM/Role authorization letting consumers assume the role?


Have you considered an alternate approach, such as having the other accounts invoke the Lambda function directly (without using API Gateway), and managing access by granting permissions to the IAM credentials that they will use to invoke Lambda? This method does not require any networking configuration.

That can work too, can you provide an example, and would that work with a private zone too?

What are your high-level objectives? It seems to be the ability to invoke a Lambda function from various AWS Accounts and Regions. Presumably, you also want to restrict such access to only specific sources / credentials. What is driving your requirement to have a 'private zone'? (I think that simply refers to having local DNS resolution, rather than connectivity.)

You indicated that "Lambda already lives in a VPC with strict SG and private subnets." so you're misunderstanding something fundamental about Lambda functions. Lambda function invocation is not controlled by VPC networking or security groups. Invocation does not happen via VPC networking. A request to invoke a Lambda function is an API request to the AWS Lambda service itself, not to the Lambda function. The Lambda function is invoked by the AWS Lambda service control plane, not by a networking request that traverses the VPC.

By default, AWS Lambda functions can be invoked via API calls on the Internet. Code running anywhere can invoke a Lambda function by calling the Invoke API using any AWS SDK.
Also, Lambda functions can be invoked via a Lambda function URL, which is similar to API Gateway but talks to the AWS Lambda service directly.
Both of these options can be secured with IAM credentials.
Thus, it would be a lot simpler to have your various services invoking the AWS Lambda function directly by calling endpoints on the Internet. It does not require any networking, private endpoints or hosted zones.
Also, please note that AWS Lambda functions should only be connected to a VPC if the code in the function needs to access resources within that VPC. If it does not need to access resources in the VPC, then do not connect the Lambda function to the VPC.

Oh right. Yes in this case I should mention that Lamba does need to be in a VPC that has an interface endpoint to another service

That's fine. Please note that triggering/invoking an AWS Lambda function can be done via the Internet. It does not require access to the VPC where the Lambda function is connected.

Ok doing internet can be fine, can I also consider the lambda service interface endpoint? If so, I am just wondering how the cross region affect (or not)

I don't think a VPC Endpoint will work when connecting to a service in a different region. Looks like it requires VPC Peering, see: Configure cross-Region VPC endpoints for AWS services | AWS re:Post

While this would still be assuming I'd be calling invoke API and the peering would only be to resolve the DNS name of the Lambda in another region.
In other words, I won't have to directly set up a VPC to VPC connection but I could invoke the API and make sure the call won't travel outside AWS network through Internet.
Correct?

The linked document seems to suggest you'll need to setup VPC Peering (which is a 'VPC to VPC connection') to keep the traffic within the AWS network.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
